# Can a scammer withdraw from a wallet if I revoke permissions?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, wallet-transfer, scam

A friend of mine went last night to a scam web, clicked on a button and some Pendle tokens were withdrew on the Ethereum blockchain.

I checked the transactions and there are two: Approval() and Transfer()

My questions are:

- Once he revoked the permission, Can the contract transfer more tokens?
- There are only one approval for Pendel token. There's a chance contract can transfer other tokens?
- What's about ETH? Can the contract withdraw ETH? I never saw one approval request for ETH, so I don't know if any contract can withdraw ETH.
- Is the wallet safe on Ethereum blockchain?
- Is the wallet safe on Ethereum blockchain in other blockchains?

It's not a disposable wallet because he have some Defi product on it and would prefer to keep using it.

Comment: It depends on the contract implementation. Popular token contracts have a standard implementation and they should be reasonable secure.

Comment: So, it depends only on the token contract or also the "blockchain" contract?

I mean: Pendle token, by example, is a very popular token. So his contract is supposed to hace a standard implementation. But, he approved to use the Pendle token on a blockchain contract. And I don't know if there's a way that blockchain contract can drain tokens after revoke of permissions.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what "blockchain contract" means. In Ethereum all the contracts run on the blockchain's EVM.

Comment: By "blockchain contract" I meant a contract that is not a token contract, like a liquidity pool, swap, etc...

Comment: In Ethereum all contracts are the same. They can do anything they want. Usually popular contracts like Uniswap, Usdt, Dai, etc. are well known, have frequent audits, and are reasonable secure. It doesn't mean they are safe, an unknown bug could exist. You should only grant permissions to contract you can trust the team behind them. Unverified contract, or contract you got from a telegram channel are dubious at best.

Comment: Ok, all contracts are the same. Buy do they can interact with a wallet if permission have been revoked?

Comment: The EVM doesn't have a permission system. Each contract uses its own implementation. A common implementation is from the OpenZeppelin contracts, which is reasonable audited and safe. But I can't make a general statement a contract can use an old OpenZeppelin implementation, or make changes that weren't audited, etc. Is it better to revoke permissions that you don't use? Yes. Will your wallet be safe? I don't know without auditing the contracts.

Comment: Thank you very much.